# Extract Rows from JSON Google API request in R

Tags: json, r, google-maps-api-3, jsonlite

I am pulling in data from banks based on a search nearby request from Google's map api.  In some instances, It pulls more than one bank (as some banks may be close together).  How do I go about extracting each individual JSON object returned (as I need to get the place id) in order that I can do a second api pull (based on the place id) to search more detail about each bank?  Here is my code:

```
require(jsonlite)
require(utils)


plcUrl <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
key <- "myKEY"
location <- paste0("41.0272, -81.51345")
address <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
type <- "bank"
radius <- "500"
name = "XXXXX"
strurl <- as.character(paste(plcUrl ,
                             "&location=",location,
                             "&address=",address,
                             #"&name=",name,
                             "&radius=",radius,
                             "&type=",type,
                             "&key=",key,
                             sep=""))
setInternet2(TRUE)
rd <- fromJSON(URLencode(strurl))
rd$results$place_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of googleway v2.4 I've added methods that access specific elements of Google API queries.

```
library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

## search places
res <- google_places(location = c(41.0272, -81.51345),
                    key = key,
                    place_type = "bank",
                    radius = 500)


## get the place_id values using the `place` method to extract the ids
place(res)
# [1] "ChIJDe7R2HQqMYgRvqoszlV6YTA" "ChIJDQwLUXMqMYgR-3Nb2KFhZZ0"

## query the details
details <- google_place_details(place_id = place(res)[1], key = key)

details$result$opening_hours
# $open_now
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $periods
#   close.day close.time open.day open.time
# 1         1       1600        1      0900
# 2         2       1600        2      0900
# 3         3       1600        3      0900
# 4         4       1600        4      0900
# 5         5       1800        5      0900
# 6         6       1300        6      0900
# 
# $weekday_text
# [1] "Monday: 9:00 AM – 4:00 PM"    "Tuesday: 9:00 AM – 4:00 PM"   "Wednesday: 9:00 AM – 4:00 PM" "Thursday: 9:00 AM – 4:00 PM" 
# [5] "Friday: 9:00 AM – 6:00 PM"    "Saturday: 9:00 AM – 1:00 PM"  "Sunday: Closed"
```

Comment: does googleway yet access opening hours?  I have stayed away from your package due to that fact, as that is what I am looking for.  thanks!

Comment: @CooperBuckeye05 - I've added a [feature request](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/87) to implement a `places_open()` method to extract that data directly. I'll update this question when it's done.

Comment: @CooperBuckeye05 - i've made the update to add a `place_hours` function to the dev version